# Join on the same table in DB2

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have a table like

```
col1 col2 col3
abc  123  A
abc  345  B
def  567  A
ghi  890  B
```

I want to have the data in one row related to an element. Col3 is the discriminator element. Only the 'A' and 'B' rows are related. Result should look like

```
col1 col2A col2B
abc  123   345
def  567   --
ghi  --    890
```

How can i do that??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Join a table to itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794875/join-a-table-to-itself)

Comment: @Ben join to itself is similar but in that case i must create only one row from two rows. using a discrimonator. You can try it with writing the query then you will understand what i mean

Comment: then it is a duplicate of many other questions. Both those questions have been asked many times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=poor+pivot+%5Btsql%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might not be case to use self join. This will work for the data you posted:

```
select 
    col1,
    max(case col3 when 'A' then col2 else null end) col2A,
    max(case col3 when 'B' then col2 else null end) col2B
from YourTable
group by col1
```

Of course, if you have data like below, it would fail:

```
col1 col2 col3
abc  123  A
abc  345  B
abc  567  A
```

Then again, not only the query would fail, but your whole business rule would fail if you have data like this.

Comment: In each category I can have only one value. It means In Category A, abc can exist only one time.

Comment: Another question. I have also a concat operation on col1. How can I write in group by part. I tried like that:   `select 
    CONCAT(' ', col1) col1Modified,
    max(case col3 when 'A' then col2 else null end) col2A,
    max(case col3 when 'B' then col2 else null end) col2B
from YourTable
group by col1Modified`

Answer (score 0):

This construct works in SQL Server. I do not have a DB2 instance handy to verify that it works there as well, but the syntax is reasonably standard.

```
SELECT t0.col1, t1.col2 AS col2A, t2.col2 AS col2B
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM mytable) as t0 -- Select the list of keys
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t1 ON t0.col1=t1.col1 AND t1.col3='A' -- Join for col2A
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2 ON t0.col1=t2.col1 AND t2.col3='B' -- Join for col2B
```