# How to refer to other row in the same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm not sure on how to write the title. So, here it is :

I've got a Doctor table and each Doctor has a Supervisor which is also among the doctors.

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- -------------
DOC_ID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
DOC_NAME                                           VARCHAR2(9)
DATEHIRED                                          DATE
SALPERMON                                          NUMBER(12)
AREA                                               VARCHAR2(20)
SUPERVISOR_ID                                      NUMBER(3)
CHGPERAPPT                                         NUMBER(3)
ANNUAL_BONUS                                       NUMBER(5)
```

If you notice, there's a SUPERVISOR_ID which is also a DOC_ID on a different row. My question is how to display the supervisor's name for each doctor?

Comment: this is a duplicate question, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794899/599911

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT d1.*,d2.DOC_NAME
FROM DOCTOR d1
INNER JOIN DOCTOR d2 ON d1.SUPERVISOR_ID = d2.DOC_ID;
```

You perform a `INNER JOIN` with the same table, and it behaves as if you were getting the `DOC_NAME` from a different table.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it. :)
Turns out what I should be asking is how to perform self join.